# Rigorously expressing time as an integral of velocity and position

Tags: physics, derivation-of-formulae

I am studying the brachistochrone problem and I have found in many books the following chain of implications for calculating the time to travel from one point $A$ to another point $B$:
$$v = \frac{dr}{dt} \implies dt = \frac{dr}{v} \implies t = \int_A^B \frac{1}{v}dr$$
As a math student, I always try to avoid treating differentials as mere numbers, but as simple as it seems I cannot find a more mathematically correct way of obtaining this expression.

I would be grateful if someone could provide a derivation or a reference.

Comment: Use the inverse function theorem to get $dt/dr$ and then the FTC to get $t(B)-t(A)$ from that. (Doing this also makes it clear how this breaks if $r(t)$ is not invertible.)